# Ionic 4 network check

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

How do I check of internet connectivity in each page in Ionic 4. The need is if there is an network error I need to redirect the app to an error page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the official Ionic Network plugin (doc [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/)).

Usage example from doc :

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx'; //ngx

constructor(private network: Network) { }

...

// watch network for a disconnect
let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('network was disconnected :-(');
});

// stop disconnect watch
disconnectSubscription.unsubscribe();


// watch network for a connection
let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('network connected!');
  // We just got a connection but we need to wait briefly
   // before we determine the connection type. Might need to wait.
  // prior to doing any api requests as well.
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.network.type === 'wifi') {
      console.log('we got a wifi connection, woohoo!');
    }
  }, 3000);
});

// stop connect watch
connectSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

Install network information plugin by using command:-

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

Then you can use following code after deviceready to execute some code when the device goes offline :-

```
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

function onOffline() {
    // Handle the offline event
    // use code to redirect here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (this.network.type === 'none') {
        this.presentAlert('network was disconnected :-(');
        setTimeout(() => {
            navigator['app'].exitApp();
        }, 4000);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.