# How to check for internet connection and to use localstorage data

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

In my home.ts file, i want to use localStorage items if internet connection is OFFLINE. Here is a code. When i add IF here i've got too many errors. I want to use this getItem below in code for '__mydb/_ionickv/DodNalog'if internet is offline.

```
    getStorageWarents() {



      this.storage.ready()
        .then(() => {
          this.warrentsInStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('__mydb/_ionickv/DodNalog'));
          console.log("Warrents in storage: ", this.warrentsInStorage);

        })
        .then(() => {
          this.getAssignedWarrents();
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.getAllGoods();
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.getAllCancelTypes();
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.getAllDeviceTypes();
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.getAllManufacturers();
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.getAllIntereventionTypes();
        })


  }
```

Comment: To help others answer your question: Are you using Ionic 4? Where exactly did you use IF statement? Will this code reproduce the error? What was the error message? These are just a couple question that could **possibly** clarify your question. Please refer to [ask].

Comment: Im using ionic 4. I want IF statement to check for localStorage username and password of logged in user and to allow him to use an app without internet connection. So IF statement will check for internet connection and if its ONLINe, it will work with webservice, if its not ONLINE, it will use localstorage items.

Comment: To check for internet connection changes, you can use [Ionic's network plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53064905/6367080)

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network use this

Answer (score 0):

To get a Network connection update on Connect/Disconnect you can use ionic Network plugin in your app.

```
Network Plugin
```

**Installation:**

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
npm install @ionic-native/network
```

**How to use?**

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';

constructor(private network: Network) { }
```

**Subscribe for Connect/Disconnect event:**

```
let disconnectSub = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('device network was disconnected');
});

let connectSub = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('Device network connected!');
  // We just got a connection but we need to wait briefly
   // before we determine the connection type. Might need to wait.
  // prior to doing any api requests as well.
  setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('we got a connection, woohoo!');
  }, 3000);
});
```

**To stop capturing above events simply Unsubscribe it**

```
disconnectSub.unsubscribe();
```

Hope this will helps to get network Connect/Disconnect status.

**Ref Link:** https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network